# Verify CRL signature against its root CA

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm currently trying to verify that the CRL I download from a URL is a valid file, signed by the corresponding Certificate Authority.

With OpenSSL, you can do this as follows :

https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/crl.html

Example with the CRL issued from CertEurope :

```
openssl crl -in certeurope_v3.crl -inform der -CAfile certeurope_advanced_v3.cer
```

(The CRL file and the CA file are downloaded from this URL : https://www.certeurope.fr/chaine-de-confiance )

- CA file :
  https://www.certeurope.fr/reference/certeurope_advanced_v3.cer
- CRL file : https://www.certeurope.fr/reference/certeurope_v3.crl

Unfortunately, OpenSSL gets an error with that commmand line saying :

> "Error getting CRL issuer certificate"

Regarding this link : https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/verify.html 
The reason seems to be this :

> 20 X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY: unable to get local
>   issuer certificate the issuer certificate could not be found: this
>   occurs if the issuer certificate of an untrusted certificate cannot be
>   found.

Is this because the CA file is not the one used to sign the CRL file ? Is there another way to verify that the CRL file I download is valid ?

Comment: Yes, that CRL is signed by that cert, but that cert link (like the CRL) is DER and `-CAfile` (and `-CApath`) **requires PEM**. Convert it with `openssl x509 -in certeurope_advanced_v3.cer -inform der -out certeurope_advanced_v3.pem` and use that instead. But using the cert from the website to validate the CRL from the website isn't really secure; if the site is fraudulent or compromised, they could BOTH actually be invalid.

Comment: Thanks, it works ! Can you answer my question so I can mark it as resolved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dave_thompson_085 's answer fixed my problem. You need a PEM certificate to check CRL validity. Thanks again.