# CRL validity openssl

Tags: linux, openssl, client-certificates, public-key, certificate-revocation

I need to verify that the downloaded crl is actually the one generated by the CA, and not modified by a potential attacker.
is there any way to verify this with openssl commands from linux os?

In other words, i need **to verify CRL signature against its root CA**, i already found this link, but not helps me much.
[Verify CRL signature against its root CA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34284375/verify-crl-signature-against-its-root-ca)

Answer (score 3):

openssl has a command to verify the signature of the downloaded crl against the issuing certificate authority.

```
openssl crl -verify -in <crl file> -CAfile < issue certificate or cert chain>
```

Here is a hello-world example of verifying GOOGLE CRL against the Google issuer CA certificate

1. Download the google crl using wget

   `wget http://crl.pki.goog/GTS1O1core.crl`
2. Downloaded CRL is DER format , convert it to PEM format

   `openssl crl -inform DER -in GTS1O1core.crl -outform PEM -out google_crl.pem`
3. Download google certificate chain

   `OLDIFS=$IFS; IFS=':' certificates=$(openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 -showcerts -tlsextdebug -tls1 2>&1 </dev/null | sed -n '/-----BEGIN/,/-----END/ {/-----BEGIN/ s/^/:/; p}'); for certificate in ${certificates#:}; do echo $certificate | tee -a google-cert-chain.pem ; done; IFS=$OLDIFS`
4. Verify the downloaded CRL against issue certificate ( available in the downloaded cert chain in 3)

   `openssl crl -verify -in google_crl.pem -CAfile google-cert-chain.pem`